# Why doesn't \ifx work inside a node command in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following piece of code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\pos{5,5}    
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}    
  \node (b)  at (0,0) {test};
  \node (a) \ifx\pos\pgfutil@empty\else at(\pos)\fi {something};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to test if the macro `\pos` holds a position or not and in case it does I want to use it to print the node. However, when I compile the example above I get some errors in the way of:

> Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text.
>
> Use of `\@next` doesn't match its definition.

What am I doing wrong? Or in which way can I achieve my goal of testing the macro for display?

Comment: see

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The error is raised *before* `\pgfutil@empty` is examined, but of course the `@` problem is relevant anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the part:

> Or in which way can I achieve my goal of testing the macro for display?

Here's a method using `pgfkeys` to define a style `tripos` (with apologies to any Cambridge graduates present) which examines `\pos` to see if it is empty or not, and if not then it uses `\pgfkeys` to call the `at` key to set the node's position.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\pos{5,5}    

\tikzset{tripos/.code={%
    \unless\ifx\pos\empty
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/at=(\pos)}
    \fi
  }
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}    
  \node (b)  at (0,0) {test};
  \node[tripos] (a) {something};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(As David Carlisle notes in his comment on your question, using the `@` requires `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` wizardry.  As you're using LaTeX, we can test against `\empty` instead of `\pgfutil@empty` and so avoid this issue.)

Answer (score 4):

When TikZ looks for an `at` specification after `\node (a)`, it doesn't expand tokens. So in your case it finds `\ifx` which it doesn't like.

If you really need such a test, the following hack works:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (b)  at (0,0) {test};
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\node (a) \ifx\pos\empty\else at(\pos)\fi}
  \x {something};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

as it expands the conditional *before* TikZ can see `\node`.

Note that you can't use `\pgfutil@empty` unless you set `\makeatletter` before the `tikzpicture` environment (it seems overkill to me).

Comment: I don't mean to be overly critical, and this is a nice showcase of a clever trick, but is the `\begingroup` thing really necessary?  So what if another macro name gets defined, or `\x` gets overwritten?  It seems more instructive to give the minimal effective code performing "compute first, then expand the result".

Comment: With this code, you're sure that *nothing* will be overwritten. The only disallowed tokens are `\noexpand\x` in the replacement text, which wouldn't be meaningful anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. However, you say "if you really need such a test," is there any other way to achieve the same result but in a different way?

Comment: @egreg Even `\noexpand\x` can be used in the replacement text without trouble. The definition of `\x` that you created only lives from the end of the `\edef` to the end of the group, i.e., just long enough to expand that `\x` once.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I had this doubt, indeed. Thanks.